# Multiple Constructors with same arguments

Tags: java, constructor, equals

I'm trying to set up a constructor where a the data structure used will be determined by a string in the parameter::

```
DictionaryI<IPAddress,String> ipD; //declaring main structure using interface

 // Constructor, the type of dictionary to use (hash, linkedlist, array)
 // and the initial size of the supporting dictionary
    public IPManager(String dictionaryType, int initialSize){
        if(st1.equals(dictionaryType))
            ipD = new LinkedListDictionary();
        if(st2.equals(dictionaryType))
            ipD = new HashDictionary(initialSize);
        if(st3.equals(dictionaryType))
            ipD = new ArrayDictionary(initialSize);
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

when running the code I get "UnsuportedOperationException" no matter what I put in. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! (Code is in Java)

Comment: Care to give us st1, st2 and st3?

Comment: st1 = "linkedlist"
st2 = "hash"
st3 = "array"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious answer is

```
public IPManager(String dictionaryType, int initialSize){
    if(st1.equals(dictionaryType))
        ipD = new LinkedListDictionary();
    else if(st2.equals(dictionaryType))
        ipD = new HashDictionary(initialSize);
    else if(st3.equals(dictionaryType))
        ipD = new ArrayDictionary(initialSize);
    else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

For `st1` and `st2` your code would fall through to the `throw`.

That said, this approach is generally bad.  For reference look at the Java collection interfaces (`Map<K,V>` for instance) and its implementations (`HashMap`, `TreeMap`, etc).

Comment: Look at your original post -- you left off the `else` keywords.

Comment: And if you want to stick to this approach, consider at least switching to an enum for the dictionary types instead of hardcoded strings

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried it originally with the else if, and it didn't work, although it works now since I asked you guys(weird how that works here as well as in IT helpdesk, although I probalby did something wrong with my earlier code too).  

It's for a school project so were not allowed to use Java collections and have to code the data structures ourselves.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I meant you should look at how the Java collections define an interface and several implementations to guide your design, instead of using a string to indicate the implementation type.

Comment: Ah I see.  Unfortunately, the project required that we used a specific string(hash,array,linkedlist) to set which data structure we are using.  All structures do use a dictionary interface that was provided to us.

Comment: Welcome to the world of bad pre-specified designs.  At least this mirrors the real world, where you _will_ find all sorts of less-than-optimal specifications.